# How to Dynamically allocate the array size of your char variable based on the length of the user's input?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, heap-memory

I need to let the user enter his first name and store it in an array `char` and the size of this array is dynamically located depend on user name that he entered.

This is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    static int size = 5 ;
    printf("please Enter Your First Name..\n");

    char* p = (char*)malloc(size*sizeof(char));

    for(int i = 0 ; i <= sizeof(p) ; i++)
    {
        if(sizeof(p)+1 == size )
        {
            p = (char*)realloc(p,2*size*sizeof(char));
            size = sizeof(p);
        }
        else
        {
            scanf("%c",&p[i]);
        }

    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i <=size ; i++)
    {
        printf("%s",*(p+i));
    }

free(p);

}
```

I give the array a first size of 5 `char`, then if the user name length is more that this size, Its realloc in heap a double size of the size,

and I make a condition  `if(sizeof(p)+1 == size )` because `sizeof(p) = 4` , so I need 5 = 5 so thats I put `sizeof(p)+1`.

But my code is not working. Why?

Comment: I would do it by allocating a buffer that will be plenty big enough, and afterwards shrink to size by reallocating. Rellocating for every character is very inefficient. If you must use that approach IMO it would be better to work in chunks of 8 bytes (in other words you allocate 8 bytes when you run out of space). It is unlikely that the memory allocation will have a better granularity than that, so you won't be wasting memory.

Comment: @WeatherVane, i think for create a buffer , but i think it will be the same since i give a initial size for array

Comment: What is the `sizeof(p)` for? That is the size of the buffer *pointer* not the buffer. You cannot obtain the size of the memory allocation, except by tracking it with your own variable. You need two variables, one for the buffer size, and one for the amount you have used.

Comment: @WeatherVane size of pointer ,

Comment: Well, `sizeof(p)+1` will always give the same value no matter how much reallocation you do.

Comment: @WeatherVane oh, you are right!! , i checked it now , so how can i get the size of pointer ?

Comment: The size of the pointer is irrelevant, I already [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62369921/how-to-dynamically-allocate-the-array-size-of-your-char-variable-based-on-the-le#comment110306580_62369921) what you should do.

Comment: @WeatherVane , i try alot , but it doesnt work , can you give me any code for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common mistake is to use `sizeof(pointer)` to get the size of the memory it points to. Here is some sample code for you to try.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>             // required header files

#define CHUNK 1  // 8           // amount to allocate each time

int main(void)                  // correct definition
{
    size_t size = CHUNK;        // prefer a larger size than 1
    size_t index = 0;
    int ch;                     // use the right type for getchar()
    char *buffer = malloc(size);
    if(buffer == NULL) {
        // handle erorr
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Please enter your first name\n");
    while((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n') {
        if(index + 2 > size) {       // leave room for NUL
            size += CHUNK;
            char *temp = realloc(buffer, size);
            if(temp == NULL) {
                // handle erorr
                exit(1);
            }
            buffer = temp;
        }
        buffer[index] = ch;
        index++;
    }

    buffer[index] = 0;               // terminate the string
    printf("Your name is '%s'\n", buffer);
    printf("string length is %zu\n", strlen(buffer));
    printf("buffer size   is %zu\n", size);

    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Program session:

```
Please enter your first name
Weather
Your name is 'Weather'
string length is 7
buffer size   is 8
```

I would prefer to use a larger buffer size, as that is less stress on the system, and because memory allocated probably uses a minimum size anyway. When I set

```
#define CHUNK 8
```

the session is

```
Please enter your first name
Wilhelmina
Your name is 'Wilhelmina'
string length is 10
buffer size   is 16
```

Comment: Thank you master , you made my day , but i have one question    if(index + 2 > size) what is the aim from this condition ?

Comment: The buffer must be large enough for the next character **and** the NUL terminator (written after the loop). The initial size of the array is one, and if the first character is newline, you get the empty string.

Comment: hello bro again , what does mean         buffer[index] = ch; why i need this line ? and this buffer[index] = 0;

Comment: `buffer[index] = ch;` is building the array of characters that you typed. `buffer[index] = 0;` is writing the nul terminator which is needed to make it a string.